# How to remove the white space at the start of the string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I want to remove the white space which is there in the start of the string
It should remove only the space at the start of the string, other spaces should be there.

```
var string=' This is test';
```

Comment: JavaScript now has `trimStart()` and `trimEnd()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimStarttrimEnd() • https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimEnd

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
function ltrim(str) {
  if(!str) return str;
  return str.replace(/^\s+/g, '');
}
```

Also for ordinary trim in IE8+:

```
function trimStr(str) {
  if(!str) return str;
  return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}
```

And for trimming the right side:

```
function rtrim(str) {
  if(!str) return str;
  return str.replace(/\s+$/g, '');
}
```

Or as polyfill:

```
// for IE8
if (!String.prototype.trim)
{
    String.prototype.trim = function ()
    {
        // return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        return this.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
    };
}

if (!String.prototype.trimStart)
{
    String.prototype.trimStart = function ()
    {
        // return this.replace(/^\s+/g, '');
        return this.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+/g, '');
    };
}

if (!String.prototype.trimEnd)
{
    String.prototype.trimEnd = function ()
    {
        // return this.replace(/\s+$/g, '');
        return this.replace(/[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
    };
}
```

**Note:** 
\s: includes spaces, tabs \t, newlines \n and few other rare characters, such as \v, \f and \r.
\uFEFF: Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF)
\xA0: ASCII 0xA0 (160: non-breaking space) is not recognised as a space character

Comment: can you please explain /^\s+|\s+$/g

Comment: @vikramvi: It's a regex pattern (RegEx: Regular Expression) : One or more whitespace from the start of the line, or one or more white space at the end of the line. ^ means start of the line, $ means end of the line, \ is escape sequence, \s means "white-space", \s+ means one or more white-space character.

Comment: why the /g ?  If we only want at beginning while do multiple replacments?

Comment: @Garr Godfrey: Probably because I copied it from trim, which needs it (else it only removes the white-space at the start of the string. Other than performance, it should not have any adverse effect on ltrim and rtrim.

Answer (score 41):

Try to use javascript's `trim()` function, Basically it will remove the leading and trailing spaces from a string.

```
var string=' This is test';
string = string.trim();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gAuvm/)

So as per the conversation happened in the comment area, in order to attain the backward browser compatibility just use jquery's `$.trim(str)`

```
var string=' This is test';    
string = $.trim(string)
```

Comment: Just note: `trim` is supported in IE9+ browser https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: Note: The trim() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.

Comment: here i want to remove only the space which is available at the start of the string

Answer (score 15):

You can use String.prototype.trimStart(). Like this:

```
myString=myString.trimStart();
```

An if you want to trim the tail, you can use:

```
myString=myString.trimEnd();
```

Notice, this 2 functions are not supported on IE. For IE you need to use polyfills for them.

Comment: this is actually amazing

Answer (score 3):

Easiest solution: (ES10 feature trimStart())

```
var string= 'This is a test';
console.log(string.trimStart());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [javascript trim function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)

```
var str = "       Hello World!        ";
alert(str.trim());
```

**This function can also remove white spaces from the end of the string.**

Comment: Note: The trim() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

Just a different and a not so efficient way to do it

```js
var str = "   My string";

function trim() {
  var stringStarted = false;
  var newString = "";

  for (var i in str) {
    if (!stringStarted && str[i] == " ") {
      continue;
    }
    else if (!stringStarted) {
      stringStarted = true;
    }
    newString += str[i];
  }
  
  return newString;
}

console.log(trim(str));
```

I am really sure this doesn't work for anything else and is not the most optimum solution, but this just popped into my mind

Answer (score 1):

`.trimLeft()` can be used for this.

```
const str = "   string   ";
console.log(str.trimLeft());     // => "string   "
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove the space (i.e whitespace) at the beginning of the string. So, could not use standard jquesy `.trim()`. You can use the regex to find and replace the whitespace at the beginning of the string.

Try this:

```
.replace(/^\s+/g, "")
```

[Read this post](http://www.toptip.ca/2010/02/javascript-trim-leading-or-trailing.html)

Try this:

```
var string='    This is test   ';
alert(string.replace(/^\s+/g, ""));
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/P9jSL/11/)

OR if you want to remove the whitespace from the beginning and end then use [.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery just add ".trim()" to the end. It'll get rid of all "\n\r" and beginning + end spaces.

Answer (score -1):

```
var string=' This is test';    
$.trim(string);
```

Comment: This will remove whitespace from the end of the string which the user has stated he wants to keep