# How can I delete whitespace at beginning of string but allow whitespace at middle?

Tags: typescript

How can I delete whitespace at beginning of string but allow whitespace at middle?

```html
<mat-form-field fxFlex="25">
  <input matInput placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="userCreation.name" name="name" 
        (keypress)="Lastnamecheck($event)" minlength="3" maxlength="30" #name="ngModel" 
        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && name.invalid }" required>
  <mat-error *ngIf="f.submitted && name.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
    <mat-error *ngIf="name.errors.required"> Name is required</mat-error>
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

```ts
Lastnamecheck(event: any) {
    const pattern = /^\S+[a-zA-Z0-9-_\\s]+$/;
    let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    if (event.keyCode != 8 && !pattern.test(inputChar)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: How about `trim()`?

Comment: how can i restrict while entering only??

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282158/javascript-how-to-remove-the-white-space-at-the-start-of-the-string

** Just use string.trim()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
const inputStr = '     something in here';
const stripped = inputStr.replace(/^\s*(.*)$/, '$1');
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rs70u61L/)