# how to remove trailing and leading spaces from textbox input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, whitespace, onchange, trim

if I have something like this:

```
  return array.map(item => (
<input type="text" value={item.name}> onChange ={(name) => changeItemName(name.target.value)}
```

where the changeItemName function is basically a function that will change the name attribute of the current item. How can I go about making sure that the name attribute wont have any trailing or leading spaces? I can do something like this in my changeItemName function:

```
changeItemName(name){
name.trim()
... logic to change name of item }
```

However since I am using `onChange()`, this method is called everytime a character is typed. This means that if a user types a regular space between 2 words, this wouldnt work because the name passed into the function would be trimmed thus now allowing any spaces. How can I tweak this so that spaces still work but leading and trailing white spaces are gone?

Comment: does this give your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282158/how-to-remove-the-white-space-at-the-start-of-the-string

Answer (score 1):

You can trim the `name` when the user finished typing. For example when the input got out of focus. Try this:

```
<input type="text" value={item.name}>
    onChange ={(name) => changeItemName(name.target.value)}
    onBlur={()=> { item.name = item.name.trim() }} 
/>
```

Here the `onBlur` function would fire when user goes to some other input or other part of your website.

Comment: This works but wouldnt this mutate the state of item?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by mutate. If you mean change the state of the item well yes. It only changes the name but if there is a `useEffect` (or any part of the app) that reruns when you change the item, it would run when `onBlur` runs..

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, one is to use a debouncing function that will trim the input after the user stops typing for a couple hundred milliseconds. The other option is to trim the input on the blur event.